# Best way to retrieve _id from URL or from Iron Router

Tags: meteor

Lets say for instance my url is localhost:3000/posts/98Xjsd39sdk, with my unique id being the last part of that URL. Is there a built in way to grab that parameter that is being passed in? I know I can also pass a data object with Iron Router, but this data seems limited to being used in the actual template with handle bars {{like-this}}. What is the best way to grab on to this parameter, I'm having trouble being able to grab it and push it console.log. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in way in Meteor to extract it, but you can use plain JavaScript:

```js
var parts = location.href.split('/')
var id = parts.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure whether I understood what you are trying to achieve so please leave a comment if this is not what you wanted:.

You can declare you route with a wildcard parameter like so:

```
this.route('post', {
    path: "/posts/:postId"
});
```

Then you can acces the postId via `this.params.postId`. You can do `this.params.postId` anywhere in the route, for example in the data-part.

To make the id available to your template 'post' (if your template is called something else, you of course have to change the name in the route), just do:

```
this.route('post', {
    path: "/posts/:postId",
    data: function(){
        console.log(this.params.postId)
        return {postId: this.params.postId};
    }
});
```

Then just use {{postId}} in your template.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! I understand how to use it use it in the template by pushing the data with Iron Router, but I'm actually trying to just use it in the logic behind the scenes. I didn't know if the data passed can only be used only in the html template or if it can also be used in the javascript file that controls the template if that make sense. Is the data available without doing something similar to Pepe's answer above, if that makes sense?

Comment: @user3927685, you can get the current route with `Router.current()`. This will evaluate to an object with information about the current route, including the params (I guess). With this, you should be able to create a custom helper function doing what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var help = Router.current().params.postId
```

in your template will get the Id of the post.

if you have defined your route as such:

```
Router.route('/posts/:postId', function () {
 //subscriptions go here
 if (this.ready()) {
   this.render('postsTemplate');
 } else {
   this.render('loadingTemplate');
 }
)};
```